# Invalid object name 'syscomments' when connecting to SQL database in Azure

Tags: sql-server, f#, type-providers

I am trying to use the [SqlDataConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh362320.aspx) type provider to connect to a SQL database on Azure.

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataConnection<"Server=tcp:123456.database.windows.net,1433;Database={database};User ID={user};Password={password};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;">
```

When I try to connect to the database with the associated connection string I get the following error:

> Invalid object name 'syscomments'.

I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem other that using a different method to connect to the database (such as FSharp.Data.SqlClient). I believe this is related to the Azure implementation of Sql Server however I am unable to find any information on how to solve this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try googling for the error? I see that other people have had problems in Azure with it (independent of F#) going back to 2008! They seem to have tried various things -- perhaps one will work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the Microsoft Sql Type Provider.  I started using this Sql Type Provider to better results: http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/

Thanks to Ross McKinley for pointing me to it.